# Sonarqube file exclusion rule not working

Tags: sonarqube, wildcard, sonar-runner

I have written Sonarqube file exclusion rules. But it doesn't seem working. The intention is to **exclude all files contain "jquery" in the file name in one or more directories inside "static"**. below is the rule

```
/static/**/*jquery*.js
```

is the above rule written correctly? is it case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your path likely isn't "static", so instead of

```
/static/**/*jquery*.js
```

Try

```
**/static/**/*jquery*.js
```